# Invalid Comparator with object sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector, struct

I've overloaded the std::greater_equal<>() operator so it sorts my objects by a specific member in the struct.

```
bool operator >= (const Copys& c) const {
    return (relevence >= c.relevence);
}
```

(Did I even do that right?)

And it's just hitting me with the **Invalid Comparator** every time.  It worked once, then I ran it again and it didn't.
Calling sort like this:

```
std::sort(objs.begin(), objs.end(), std::greater_equal<Copys>());
```

I'm completely stumped any help would be awesome.

Comment: Shouldn't `operator>=()` take two arguments to match `std::greater_equal<Copys>`?

Comment: No it says "too many parameters for this operator function" when I do that.

Comment: The reference documentation says otherwise: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ — not if it’s a member function.

Comment: @pete [sure?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ — the function call operator for `std::greater_equal` takes two arguments, but it returns `lhs >= rhs`, which works just fine when a type defines a member `operator>=` that takes a single argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires a strict weak ordering, where one of the requirements is `compare(x, x) == false` (No element is ordered-before itself). That is not satisfied since `std::greater_equal<Copys>()(x, x) == true` for all `x`.

You probably want `std::greater<Copys>()` (And an `operator>`)

Comment: Yeah that worked perfect thank you!